# Exec a command from echo base64

Tags: bash, exec

I need to exec the result from this command:

```
echo 'curl http://google.com' | openssl enc -base64 | openssl enc -base64 -d
```

The result is:

```
curl http://google.com
```

but I need to do actually the curl not just echo it.

Comment: This command will just echo "curl google.com", what else should it do? You pass a string to openssl for encode, then for decode. Why? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use echo, it doesn't execute its parameter! Just do:

`curl http://google.com | openssl enc -base64 | openssl enc -base64 -d`

This takes the stdout generated by the curl command and pipes it to the next command.